# How to display multiple related objects in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have two models that look like this:

```
class EventDrink(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    drink_active = models.BooleanField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class EventIngredient(models.Model):
    drink = models.ManyToManyField(EventDrink)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    url = models.URLField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I now want to display all drinks with `drink_active` set to True to display in my view. I also want to display the ingredients related to that drink.
I know I can filter on the drinks in my view like this:

```
drinks = EventDrink.objects.filter(drink_active=1)
```

But how do I now display the ingredients related to each drink?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the related ones with:

```
my_drink.eventingredient_set.all()
```

this will trigger a query to fetch the related `EventIngredient`s. If we have to do that for several drinks that is not very efficient. We can use [**`.prefetch_related(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) to batch all these requests in one additional query, so:

```
drinks = EventDrink.objects.filter(drink_active=True).prefetch_related(
    'eventingredient_set'
)
```

We can then for example enumerate over the drinks and their ingredients:

```
for drink in drinks:
    print(drink.name)
    for ingredient in drink.eventingredient_set.all():
        print(f' - {ingredient.name}')
    print()
```

Comment: And how do I now display them properly in my Template? Cause that's where I'm stuck.

Comment: `{% for drink in drinks %}` and then `{% for ingredient in drink.eventingredient_set.all %}`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this.

```
drinks = EventDrink.objects.filter(drink_active=True)

drink_ingredients = []

for drink in drinks:
    ingredients = drink.eventingredient_set.all()
    drink_ingredients.append({'drink': drink, 'ingredients': ingredients})
```

Then you can use `drink_ingredients` in your context sent to html file.